# backHistory with phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have two page, page 1 and page 2. page 1 contains fields will contain values ​​and a Next button to go to page 2. Page 2 contains a button before allowing back to page 1. how to display the page 1 when return from page 2 with the same data input before.

i use this code:

```
navigator.app.backHistory();
return false;
```

the problem that there are fields dynamically populate combobox and if I use your code it contained the charge again of these fields are dynamic, and I lost what I selected before.

how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could Always set values of the form into local storage in the function that changes your page to page 2.  Then when you go back have it set the values of the of your form fields with the values that you set in local storage.

e.g. If it was a textarea you could do this for going to page 2

```
sessionStorage.setItem("textvalue", document.getElementById('textarea').value);
            $.mobile.changePage("page2.html", {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: false,
                reloadPage:true,
                changeHash: false

            });
```

and on page 1 have for when you go back

`$("#textarea").val(sessionStorage.getItem("textvalue");`

hope this helps